# Cbuffer Padding Error

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

In my cbuffer in DirectX, I send 2 variables over to my HLSL shader called `Light` & `Roughness`. If I remove the `Roughness` variable my program compiles fine but as soon as I introduce `Roughness` I get the error: 
`Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDDEFA0030 (d3d11.dll) in Eagle Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000000000C0.`

On the HLSL side the light variable contains it's defined value that was set in C++ and works fine without `Roughness`. If anyone could help me that would be great, I've included the necessary code below.

**effects.fx**

```
#include "Common.hlsl"

struct Light
{
    float3 dir;
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
};

cbuffer cbPerFrame
{
    Light light;
    float Roughness;
};

cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 WVP;
    float4x4 World;
};

Texture2D ObjTexture;
SamplerState ObjSamplerState
{
    Filter = ANISOTROPIC;
    MaxAnisotropy = 16;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

float3 DirectDiffuseBRDF(float3 diffuseAlbedo, float nDotL)
{
    return (diffuseAlbedo * nDotL);
}

VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 inPos : POSITION, float2 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD, float3 normal : NORMAL)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;

    output.Pos = mul(inPos, WVP);

    output.normal = mul(normal, World);

    output.TexCoord = inTexCoord;

    return output;
}

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 textureColor = ObjTexture.Sample(ObjSamplerState, input.TexCoord);

    float nDotL = saturate(dot(input.normal, light.dir));

    float3 diffuseLighting = textureColor * light.ambient * light.diffuse * Roughness;
    diffuseLighting += saturate(DirectDiffuseBRDF(textureColor, nDotL));

    return float4(diffuseLighting, textureColor.a);
}
```

**In my Main.cpp**

```
constbuffPerFrame.light = light;
constbuffPerFrame.Roughness = 1.0f;

devcon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerFrameBuffer, 0, NULL, &constbuffPerFrame, 0, 0);
devcon->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerFrameBuffer);
```

**Header.h**

```
struct Light
{
    Light()
    {
        ZeroMemory(this, sizeof(Light));
    }
    XMFLOAT3 dir;
    float pad;
    XMFLOAT4 ambient;
    XMFLOAT4 diffuse;
    XMFLOAT4 specular;
};

struct cbPerFrame
{
    Light  light;
    float Roughness;
};

Light light;
cbPerFrame constbuffPerFrame;
```

Comment: Are you using visual studio?  if you are you can use the visual debugger to closer study what happens
you can find it under debug->graphics->startthegraphicaldebugger

Comment: Suggested reading: [Packing Rules for Constant Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You fill the constbufferperframe object in your C++ code but when calling UpdateSubresourcem you pass a _cbperframe object to the function. Or just a typo?

Comment: @JánosTuránszki My entire post contained typos, didn't explain what the problem was, didn't include proper code or what the error was. I've updated my post to include those things (hopefully to make it more clear).

Comment: "Light  light;" and what's the layour of this struct?  I ask because it's almost certainly a packing problem and if so you should read and understand the link I posted.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou  `Light light` works fine, (I'm updating the code to include it) it's when I introduce Roughness where problems are caused. Since I am somewhat new to DirectX (as you can tell) could you specifically point out what the problem is & how I can fix it? I'm currently reading the link you suggested.

Comment: In your C++ side light structure you have a specular, but in your shader side structure you do not, You are also not padding after the roughness in the C++ side structure. You need to add 3 more floats of padding after roughness.

Comment: @JánosTuránszki I made the change to the Light structure. Currently I'm following some Online DirectX tutorials so I'm still a little confused what padding actually is. Could you explain what you mean when you say **You need to add 3 more floats of padding after roughness**.

Comment: You need that because alignment is enforced to be on 16 byte boundaries in the shader. The constant buffer size thus need to be multiple of 16 bytes. If I remember correctly, the createbuffer call doesn't even succeed if it is not multiple of 16 bytes, and the debug layer also throws an error message.

Comment: This seemed to fix it: `struct cbPerFrame
{
 Light  light;
 float Roughness;
 float pad;
 float pad2;
 float pad3;
};` So basically you need to have enough variables in there to equal to 16 bytes?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not padding after the roughness in the C++ side structure. You need to add 3 more floats of padding after roughness so that the buffer size is a multiple of 16 bytes.

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632(v=vs.85).aspx) you can read a more complete explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the MSDN documentation it mentions things like 1 x 16, 2 x 16, 3 x 16 elements. How do you determine which is which and how to 'pad' it? All the jargon in the MSDN page has me a little clueless.

Comment: When a variable would overflow the 16 byte boundary, then the previous variable is padded, and the new one will be placed on the next 16 bytes. The article just gives you a few examples for this.

Comment: So should all variables with a set value come before the variables pad, pad1, pad2 etc... ?

Comment: No, for example if you would like to add an other float value, just replace a padding value with that. If you'd like to add a float3 value, replace pad,pad1,pad2 values with that. If you'd like to add a float4, then it should either go before the roughness, or after pad2.

Comment: What are the byte sizes for `float`, `float2`, `float3`, `float4`? So basically all the variables within the buffer should multiply to give 16 bytes?

Comment: A float is 4 bytes, the others are multiples of that. You only have to ensure you are staying within 16 bytes at all times, because otherwise, your data will be placed to the next 16 byte register.